# Получить содержимое тега после вызова функции js

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пишу парсер на bs4. Проблема в том, что на нужном сайте есть блок iframe, который меняется в зависимости от нажатой кнопки. Сама кнопка вызывает функцию `ajax2(1168336933,3)`, которая меняет контент в iframe.
Возможно ли обойтись без браузерных драйверов, и как?